# grep for letter pair occurring twice in same word

Tags: linux, grep

What would be the correct expression to find any word with a pair of letters that occur twice in same word? This is the grep I'm using but obviously it isn't working:

```
grep -E '(.{2}).*\1' input
```

example input:

```
tea sea
halal
unix
linux
Mississippi
```

output would be:

```
halal
Mississippi
```

Comment: What's your `grep` version ?

Comment: Why didn't you include a test case that fails? Or describe what you mean by "obviously not working"?

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -E '(..).*\1' input
```

The expression is thus:

```
  NODE                     EXPLANATION
  (                        group and capture to \1:
    .                        any character except \n
    .                        any character except \n
  )                        end of \1
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
  \1                       what was matched by capture \1
```

Comment: Backreferences are unsupported in extended regular expressions. I'm not sure whether some `grep` version supports it. But you can simplify to `grep '\(..\).*\1`

Comment: Define 'unsupported', as I tested my proffered command and it worked as expected.

Comment: [You can read here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html), in chapter *POSIX Extended Regular Expressions* that »The POSIX standard does not define backreferences. Some implementations do support \1 through \9, but these are not part of the standard for ERE«. And at [open group](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html) you can read that the »interpretation of an ordinary character preceded by a backslash ( '\' ) is undefined«, and digits are ordinary characters in ERE.

Comment: And the `.*` at the end of the pattern is superfluous.

Comment: FWIW, BSD `grep` (as provided by MacOS) and GNU `grep` (as provided in Ubuntu, Gentoo, and Arch) both support backrefs in extended regular expressions.

Comment: The point is, that every version of `grep` that works with your answer also works with the command of the OP, so your answer doesn't help in any way. But at least you edited the useless parts.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you combine extended regular expressions with back references. But those were intentionally left out from the standard. So use

```
grep '\(.\{2\}\).*\1' input
```

instead. Or, more simple and better to read

```
grep '\(..\).*\1' input
```

**Edit:**

On re-reading your question I see that I overread "twice *in the same word*". Your input data only contains one word per line, so it doesn't matter, but I'll change the question to contain a relevant test case.

For "twice in the same word" you can use

```
grep '\(..\)[[:alnum:]]*\1' input
```

or on some versions of `grep` with the shortcut

```
grep '\(..\)\w*\1' input
```

Answer (score 0):

POSIXly:

```
grep '\([[:alpha:]]\{2\}\)[^[:space:]]*\1'
```

Would output the lines that contain a sequence of two alphabetical characters followed by any amount of characters other than spacing ones followed by that same sequence of alphabetical characters.

Note that POSIX EREs don't support back-references, only BREs do, though some `grep` implementations support back-references in EREs as well as an extension.

Add the `-i` option if you want it to match on `Meme` for instance.

If you wanted to output only the matching words (one per line) as opposed to the whole line containing them, that couldn't be done portably with `grep`. You could use `perl` instead:

```
perl -Mopen=locale -lne 'print $& while /\S*([[:alpha:]]{2})\S*\1\S*/g'
```

With the GNU implementation of `grep`, you should be able to do the same with:

```
grep -Eo '\S*([[:alpha:]]{2})\S*\1\S*'
```